# What is the Reason to Write @param Types in All Caps, in PHP/Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php version 7.4.3, Codeigniter version 3.1.13, and VSCode for my IDE.

When I write functions I will add some notes and define the parameters, and return outputs like so.
[image]

I noticed that when I capitalize the parameter and output types, my IDE highlights them in a nice green color, as if that was what I was supposed to do all along.

[image]

Should I be capitalizing the the @param and @return datatypes, and what is the reason for doing so?

Comment: Given you're using php 7.4 - why not use native type hints and drop phpdoc?

Comment: @zerkms Why not both? Type-hinting and documentation fulfill two different purposes. As to answer the question, no, you're not supposed to capitalize them.

Comment: @ArthurBoucher I wish it was a phpdoc `@param` syntax that omits the type second time then :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid using capitalized `STRING` for PHP doc block, because it would mean that string is a class, but it is a built-in scalar type.

VSCode shows different colors in *doc block* for **built in types** and **class-types (class or interface or enum or trait)**.

If you use the capital STRING, your IDE may be confused.

I strongly recommend to use the lower string version like in your first picture. Of course it depends on your and your team's coding style, but one of the most popular PHP standard ([PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#25-keywords-and-types)) says:

> All PHP reserved keywords and types [1][2] MUST be in lower case.

Anyways, PHP allow using case insensitive names, but for readability it should be lower case. And all user defined class-types will be the "nice green color". Of course if you change the VSCode theme the colors may change.

You can play with the types and check them in VSCode.

```
/**
 * @return object|resource|array|string|float|double|int|bool|false|true|null|mixed|void|self|static|callable|never|iterable|\Traversable|\Closure|\stdClass|\Error|\Iterator
 */
function test()
{
}
```